# ElasticSearch object heap space error at launch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, heap-memory

I am new to ElasticSearch, but already in trouble.
My configuration:

- Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits
- 8 Gb RAM

I am unsuccessful at simply starting the instance, using elasticsearch.bat :

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Adter exploring SO forums as well as ElasticSearch support pages, here is what I tried:

- setting min and/or max heap memory (using SET ES_MAX_MEM and SET ES_MIN_MEM on the command line before calling elasticsearch.bat) to various values, from 256m/512m to 256m/3g ==> no change in error message
- setting heap size (using SET ES_HEAP_SIZE on the command line before calling elasticsearch.bat) to various values, from 256m to 3g ==> no change in error message
- uninstalled my Java 7 environment and fresh installed Java 8 64 bits (checked through java -version on the command line) ==> no change in error message

Surprisingly enough, I can't seem to find any logging information (no 'logs' directory present in %ES_HOME% where the elasticsearch.org documentation states it should be...)

Would anyone point me to the right direction to get the thing up and running?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried this: elasticsearch.bat ES_HEAP_SIZE=4000m

Comment: Tried it also unsuccessfully... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it sorted out by forcing JAVA_HOME to point to my fresh Java 8 install (seems 'java' command resorted to old java install although the Java 8 installer claimed it had cleaned previous installs).

Thanks a lot